# What does the axis mean?

Tags: blender-id

You know how there is the x, y, z-axis. Why is there no a,b,c. Also, there should also be a w axis to allow for zooming in and out. Plus a v axis for rotation, as their is no rotating button the use. So can the editors add that two axes to, therefore, have v, w, x, y, z-axis.

Also, I don't know what the axis' means. is it some sort of secret code i don't know about?

Comment: "guru"... There is no need for new axes as with the current cartesian coordinates you can describe geometry and motion with no issues. There is no need for a solution for a non problem. And by the way U,V, and W are used for textues. And Yes, **there is a secret code** you can read all about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping#:~:text=latitude%20and%20longitude.-,UV%20unwrapping,each%20vertex%20in%20the%20mesh.&text=Often%20a%20UV%20map%20will,to%20minimize%20seams%20and%20overlaps.

Comment: You do know this forum is for the 3d animation software 'Blender' - https://www.blender.org/

Comment: Is anyone seeing this? What is broken, your mixer grinder ? I am afraid this is the wrong place to post such things.

Comment: @Nxdhin2005  see the [edit revisions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/190489/revisions)  _IMO it's Best to simply ignore the obtuse_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axis are just a set of planes in which an image can exist, hence there are three axis, to correlate with the three planes in a 3d mesh, unless you are doing 2d animation.

Comment: Thanks. Quite helpful. So there is no secret code whatsoever. Also what about my idea of two new axes. I think it would be quite useful!!!